# How I installed JRE using Install4j from network on product setup time?

Tags: java, deployment, installation, product, install4j

I have created an installer for my Java app using Install4j.

I want to check whether JRE/JDK is installed on my system or not. This checking will be performed at the start-up of the installer. If JDK is not installed on my system ,Install4j install JDK via oracle site and after that it continue farther process.

I created an installer for MAC OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not bundle a JRE, the installer will only be able to start if a JRE is installed, otherwise it will show an error message.

install4j offers dynamic JRE bundles, where the JRE bundle is downloaded only if no installed JRE is found. You just configure the JRE bundle on the "JRE bundle" step of the media wizard and select the "Dynamic bundle" option. Then you have to host the bundle at the configured URL.

[image]

More information is available in the [documentation](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/jreBundles.html).